# Unnecessary modal renders with React and React-bootstrap app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm learning React and am working on a simple small app. The app contains a row which has tabs and a dropdown menu. From that dropdown you can open modals for adding/removing/editing said tabs.

I've noticed that all modals get their render method called when the app starts and every time I click on any of the tabs, even the currently selected tab. I'm really new to React so I'm confused if this is supposed to happen or not. The app seems to work as expected though.

Below is a super simplified version of the code with only the necessary parts:

**app.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  // ...
  // state is { modals: { addTab: false, editTab: false, removeTab: false } }

  closeModal = (modalState) => {
    const obj = this.state.modals;
    obj[modalState] = false;
    this.setState(obj);
  }

  render() {
    <div className="App container-fluid">
      // ...
      <AddTabModal showModal={this.state.modals.addTab} closeModal={this.closeModal} ... />
      // ...
    </div>
  }
}
```

**AddTabModal.js**

```
class AddTabModal extends React.Component {
  // ...
  render() {
    // This gets triggered every time I click any tab or the dropdown menu.
    // Even if the modal is not visible.
    console.log('Render add tab modal');
    return (
      <Modal show={this.props.showModal} ... >
        // ...
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={() => { this.props.closeModal('addTab'); }}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

I also read that using arrow functions inside JSX is a bad pattern, but if I change the button to:

```
<Button onClick={this.props.closeModal('addTab')}>Close</Button>
```

It should still run ONLY when I click the button, right? But the app completely locks up from the start and I get "Maximum update depth exceeded" error. I believe this is related to the above problem as I don't have any componentWillUpdate/componentDidUpdate methods in the app.

Comment: Can you please include the `Modal` import in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do to optimize:

- Make sure all props passed into the modal are immutable
- Extract the close function into a class method
- Use `PureComponent` to prevent renders unless the props change

---

```
class AddTabModal extends PureComponent {
  // ...
  onCloseModal = () => {
    this.props.closeModal('addTab');
  }

  render() {
    // This gets triggered every time I click any tab or the dropdown menu.
    // Even if the modal is not visible.
    console.log('Render add tab modal');
    return (
      <Modal show={this.props.showModal} ... >
        // ...
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.onCloseModal}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

---

> I also read that using arrow functions inside JSX is a bad pattern, but if I change the button to:

```
<Button onClick={this.props.closeModal('addTab')}>Close</Button>
```

This is because `() => this.props.closeModal('addTab')` creates a new function, that when called will close the modal. But if you just have `this.props.closeModal('addTab')` the close modal function is called immediately.

The way to avoid the extra anonymous function is by extracting it to a class method like in the code above.